# Google Sheet Table Emailing in HTML format

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, html-table

I want to apply the CSS code for odd and even row with different colors but I'm stuck at a place I don't know how to apply to this code to the body section of the table, below is my code

```
<style>
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customersbody tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
</style>  

     <table id="customers">
            <thead>
               <tr >
                  <th><?= name ?></th>
                  <th><?= target ?></th>
                  <th><?= deliveries ?></th>
                  <th><?= shortfall ?></th>
                  <th><?= advances ?></th>
                  <th><?= acheivement ?></th>         
               </tr>   
            </thead>
          <tbody>
            <? tableRangevalues.forEach(r => {?>
               <tr >
                  <td><?= r[0] ?></td>
                  <td><?= r[1] ?></td>
                  <td><?= r[2] ?></td>
                  <td><?= r[3] ?></td>
                  <td><?= r[4] ?></td>
                  <td><?= r[5] ?></td>    
               </tr> 
                  <? }) ?>   
            </tbody>
          <tfoot>
               <tr >
                   <th><?= Totalname ?></th>
                   <th><?= Totaltarget ?></th>
                   <th><?= Totaldeliveries ?></th>
                   <th><?= Totalshortfall?></th>
                   <th><?= Totaladvances ?></th>
                   <th><?= Totalacheivement ?></th> 
               </tr>   
            </tfoot>
          </table>
```

The table body row numbers can vary. so how can I add the CSS to the above code **tbody**
Note: i'm not a programmer

Comment: I'm using your code and every second row is getting formatted successfully according to `#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}`. Isn't that what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS has a rule for an ID of `customersbody`.  To apply that ID to the table body element, change

```html
<tbody>
```

to

```html
<tbody id="customersbody">
```

Comment: As I learned little coding, I actually added that part in to CSS and even tried with the table but It didn't work.

<tbody>
            <? tableRangevalues.forEach(r => {?>
               <tr >

I think is whree Im stuck with